# disabling a node without disable its children in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there any solution to disable a node in javaFX without disabling its children ?
I want to disable all nodes in a pane except one of them dynamically.
I tried this solution and other solutions like this but doesn't work and i also think it has bad performance!

```
 node.getParent().requestFocus();
   for(int i=0 ; i<pane.getChildren().size() ; i++){
       if( !pane.getChildren().get(i).isFocused()){
           pane.getChildren().get(i).setDisable(true);

       }

   }
```

Edited:

also i tried this solution:
I added a transparent pane to main pain and then add special node to it . But it doesb't work for complex components because I should keep sizes and locations of it's children !

I exactly want that user interact with one node of whole scene and other nodes should be disable .

Comment: i dnt see a use, where you want to disable its parent node and enable child node. Can you explain the scenario that your facing?

Comment: I want to that user just interact with one of nodes in scene. Each node that I want !

Comment: What i understood is, if there are 2 panes on the screen, if the user is interacting one pane, then other pane should be disable right.

Comment: no. I have more than 2 panes and I want to enable "some" nodes in one of them.

Comment: Disable all at the launch, keep track of the last one you enabled, when you need to change disable the last one and enable the other. (works only if you want to keep enabled only one at time)

Answer (score 2):

The current javadoc of *BooleanProperty disableProperty()* of Node says: "...... **Setting disable to true will cause this Node and any subnodes to become disabled**.......

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable-boolean-

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty

So you **cannot** disable one Node without its children.

Comment: Just because this is not possible with `disableProperty` doesn't mean it is not possible some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example, how we can do that. Its just small sample.
If you entered into any of the pane,then other than this all panes are disabled. So the pane which is interacting with user is active.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @version 1.0 Jun 29, 2015
 */
public class EnableAndDisableTest extends Application{

    private ObservableList<Pane> rootPanes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
     * @param primaryStage
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception{

        StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();

        VBox pane1 = new VBox();
        pane1.setPadding( new Insets( 20 ) );
        Button button = new Button( "Button on Pane_1" );
        pane1.getChildren().add( button );
        pane1.addEventHandler( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event ){
                Pane pane = (Pane) event.getSource();
                enablePane( pane );
            }
        } );

        VBox pane2 = new VBox();
        pane2.setPadding( new Insets( 20 ) );
        Button button2 = new Button( "Button on Pane_2" );

        pane2.getChildren().add( button2 );
        pane2.addEventHandler( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event ){
                Pane pane = (Pane) event.getSource();
                enablePane( pane );
            }
        } );

        VBox pane3 = new VBox();
        Button button3 = new Button( "Button on Pane_3" );
        pane3.setPadding( new Insets( 20 ) );
        pane3.getChildren().add( button3 );
        pane3.addEventHandler( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event ){
                Pane pane = (Pane) event.getSource();
                enablePane( pane );
            }
        } );

        rootPanes.addAll( pane1, pane2, pane3 );

        HBox horizontalPane = new HBox();
        horizontalPane.getChildren().addAll( rootPanes );

        rootPane.getChildren().add( horizontalPane );

        Scene scene = new Scene( rootPane );
        primaryStage.setScene( scene );

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void enablePane( Pane pane ){
        for( Pane rootPane : rootPanes ){
            if( rootPane.equals( pane ) ){
                for( Node child : rootPane.getChildren() ){
                    child.setDisable( false );
                }
                rootPane.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: blue;" );
            }
            else{
                for( Node child : rootPane.getChildren() ){
                    child.setDisable( true );
                }
                rootPane.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: white;" );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        launch( args );
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you ... but rhis not my answer because as I said I want to disable some nodes and in complex states this nodes has many parent nodes...and disabling that node and all of its parent is complex

Comment: its difficult without knowing code. So just post your code, so that we can understand situation completely.